# Show true python source instead of pycharm stubs for an extention module

Tags: python, pycharm

When navigating python code with third party libraries - `opencv` in this case - why does `pycharm` display its *stubs* instead of the actual source?

Consider when clicking on the following `imshow()` method

```
cv2.imshow("Faces found", image)
```

Then instead of navigating to the `opencv` sources - or at least to a decompiled equivalent-  we see the following:

[image]

This compares poorly to the results on `intellij` for `jvm` languages such as java and scala - in which we have the option to **Attach sources** or at the least to show *decompiled* code.  Are there any better options for `python` than this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python extensions are written in C/C++ (so there is no *"python* source" to speak of) which, unlike Java, can't be easily decompiled.

To debug them, you'll need to do that like any other binary module, using a native debugger (that would use C-level debug information if present in the module to link machine code to the sources). PyCharm doesn't have a native debugger, [this feature is reserved for JetBrains' paid product, CLion](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206018984-Developing-Python-extension-in-C-using-PyCharm).

Comment: Ah I see . Might I presume that _pure python_ libraries _are_ visible when clicking on them - that the above occurs because it is a _c_ library with python _bindings_ only?  As  a second question: I _do_ have the _CLion_ (pro trial) and fully intend to convert to paid after the trial. Is this something linkable to pycharm pro (for which I also have a paid license?)

Comment: _"the above occurs because it is a c library with python bindings only"_ -- not quite; it's a [Python extension module](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html).

Comment: AFAICS, Pycharm (Pro or not) [doesn't deal with C/C++](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html). As per the link in the answer, CLion "has Python support", whatever that means.